# Azure - storing images in storage account and linking them to records in a table

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, azure

I've set up a table on Azure and I'm uploading a receiving data via a WP7 app. For each record in the table, I'd like to attach/link to one image which can be downloaded when I download the appropriate record.

I know that the image has to be stored in blob format in an Azure Data Account and there's plenty of tutorials on that but how do I link images to records in a table?

I.E I find the record I want and access it, how do I access the image at the same time?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the fileds in you table will contain the uri for the blob that is associated with it. You will not be able to pull from blob storage and table storage within a single transaction.

Depending on the client, the blobs for your images might be make publicly available and the client could pull them directly instead of putting the extra bandwidth load on your web role/web site

Comment: I also like to treat blob names much like I would treat public routes. So I would use something like myawesome.blob.core.windows.net/sites/1/photos/20120729.jpg

Comment: If these images are to be protected to only be downloadable by one person for a period of time I'd look into using a shared access signature - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx

Comment: I need a large number of images available to many people via an app, so presumably public?